# Toast not showing field values

Tags: android, toast

Just a simple doubt here. How to show field values in a toast.

examine the code below :

```
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name)
....
....
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You," + name + "for your time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

if the user inputs Robot as name, the toast should display

> " Thank You, Robot for your time"

instead it shows

> " Thank You,androidwidget.EditText@4053ad80for your time"

Suggest how to display a variable inputted by a user to display in the toast.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should select an answer as the right one if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually get the text.

`+ name.getText().toString() +`

Will solve the issue

This is happening because just calling `name` is only returning the address of `name`. To get what `name` contains you must specify what you want to have returned via `getText()` and then make sure it is in string format using `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a reference to an `EditText`, not a `String`. You have to do this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You," + name.getText() + "for your time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `name` with `name.getText().toString()` like in your toast

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You," + name.getText().toString()+ "for your time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the "objetct" name, which is an EditText. Instead, you should pass to the Toast the string contained on that EditText, like so:

```
name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name)
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You," + name.getText().toString() + "for your time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You," + name.getText().toString()+ "for your time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```